# Is Enum a JVM wide singleton?

Tags: java, jvm, singleton

I have multiple wars deployed in jetty. Initially I had a singleton class but the problem was it was initialized in both the wars. So I'm trying by making the singleton as enum. Is there a way to make a JVM wide singleton ?

Comment: do youmean enum as a singleton ?

Comment: Yeah enum as a singleton

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't really enforce this. Your singletons will be classloader-specific, and since your apps can define multiple classloaders, you're going to be frustrated.

Comment: +1 You have to make sure your jar/war is only loaded once, which means deploying it as a shared jar.